# Is there is a way to do something like rails server --sandbox?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a way to run `rails server` in sandboxed mode?

I would want all the changes made on the rails app to be rolled back after the server is stopped.

For example, doing the command `rails console --sandbox`.

Comment: Does not seem possible, you could create a script that dump your db, start rails server, then import the dump after the server quits.

Comment: @BenjaminSinclaire, how the command "rails console --sandbox" works?
It seems be like that, it doesn't?

Comment: Why you should do that? Don't you have different setups? Development, staging and production for example? Live coding is never good!! ;-)

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this? I'm playing around with some data in a mobile app and I dont want it to persist when I close the development server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My own answer for this:

When you get the state you want to keep on your database, you should dump only the data to a SQL file and place it as a seeds file:

```
db/seeds.sql
```

After that every time you want to back to the initial state you should run:

```
bundle exec rails db:reset && bundle exec rails server
```

Answer (score 5):

There's no build in way to do this. You can start rails console in sandbox mode (rails c -s), but not server.

But... If the changes you want to be rolled back, are only changes in your data, you can just write your seeds data and populate database with them every time you run server.